# UK Tier 4 student visa

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, paperwork

I am applying for Tier 4 UK student visa. I am currently working as Project Assistant (temporary position) in one of the research laboratories in India and I receive a stipend.

Should I consider myself as employed or not employed for visa application?

If employed, what documents do I need to produce?